# Why the extension $\boldsymbol{\kappa}(\mathfrak{P}) | \boldsymbol{\kappa}(\mathfrak{p})$ is normal? (Algebraic Number Theory)

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm now reading the Jurgen Neukirch, Algebraic Number Theory, p.56

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm now trying to understand the underlined statement.

Since $L|K$ is normal(Is is assumed that $L|K$ is finite Galois in the book p.53), $f(X)$ splits over $L$ into linear factors. But why furthermore $f(X)$ splits 'over $\mathcal{O}$' ?

Can anyone helps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f(X)$ is monic, with (algebraic) integral coefficients, all of its roots will be algebraic integers, so the splitting over $L$ will give a splitting over $O$.

Comment: Yeh.. through some argument, I finally somewhat understand. Anyway your comment was helpful. Thank you!